# Reloading Cisco 881w AP reloads the whole router?

Tags: cisco, router, wlan, access-point

This is about a Cisco router (881w) with the AP-WLAN interface.

While on the AP interface (after having entered this command:)

```
service-module wlan-ap 0 session
```

If I enter this command:

```
reload
```

will this reload the **whole** router, or only the AP module? In other words, will I only lose Wifi connectivity, or the whole internet access during the reload process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only to reload the WLAN AP, type:

```
service-module wlan-ap 0 reload
```

Typing reload by itself may either do nothing, or reload the whole router.  If it will reload the whole router, it should prompt you before carrying out the action.